# expressionengine variable not parsed

Tags: parsing, tags, expressionengine

I have two custom fields: blog_title_it and blog_title_en to separate content in two different languages in the same channel.
The tag

```
{blog_title_{language_code}}
```

just works as expected, while

```
{channel_name}_title_{language_code}
```

Is rendered

```
blog_title_en
```

How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
    <ul>
    {exp:search:search_results search_in="everywhere"}
    {if language_code =="it"}
        <li><a href="{exp:replace_plus find='.com/' replace='.com/it/'}{auto_path}{/exp:replace_plus}">{channel_name}_title_{language_code}</a> (trovato in {channel}) {channel_name}_body_{language_code}</li>
    {if:else}
        <li"><strong><h3><a href="{auto_path}">{channel_name}_title_{language_code}</a></h3></strong> (from {channel}){channel_name}_body_{language_code}</li>
    {/if}
    {/exp:search:search_results}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sounds like a template parse order issue.  What kind of variable is {language_code}?

Comment: it is a global variable, could be "en" or "it". Yes it looks like a template parser order issue, any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**2nd Edit...**

Alas I can't figure out a good way to approach this. Ideally you would have created a shared field group that went across all the channels that had the same fields you want to use (e.g. title_it, title_en, etc). You could then show/hide fields as relevant using publish layouts in EE, so only the relevant fields appear for each channel. Thus removing the issue with "channel_name" in the field name.

I tried playing with different stash approaches, using the channel_name or ID as the key, but still it stumbles at the fact that you need to parse it twice.

These are the best 2 ideas I can think of...

Rubbish solution one: Basic approach:

```
<ul>
  {exp:search:search_results search_in="everywhere"}
    {if language_code =="it"}
      <li>
        <a href="{exp:replace_plus find='.com/' replace='.com/it/'}{auto_path}{/exp:replace_plus}">
          {if {channel_name} == "A"}
            {A_title_{language_code}}
        </a> (trovato in {channel}) {A_body_{language_code}}
          {if:elseif {channel_name} == "B"}
            {B_title_{language_code}}
        </a> (trovato in {channel}) {B_body_{language_code}}
          {if:elseif {channel_name} == "C"}
            {C_title_{language_code}}
        </a> (trovato in {channel}) {C_body_{language_code}}
          {/if}
      </li>
    {if:else}
      <li>
        {if {channel_name} == "A"}
          <strong><h3><a href="{auto_path}">{A_title_{language_code}}</a></h3></strong> (from {channel}){A_body_{language_code}}
        {if:elseif {channel_name} == "B"}
          <strong><h3><a href="{auto_path}">{B_title_{language_code}}</a></h3></strong> (from {channel}){B_body_{language_code}}
        {if:elseif {channel_name} == "C"}
          <strong><h3><a href="{auto_path}">{C_title_{language_code}}</a></h3></strong> (from {channel}){C_body_{language_code}}
        {/if}
      </li>
    {/if}
  {/exp:search:search_results}
</ul>
```

This would probably be nicer if you used [Stashee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee).

Rubbish solution two: Embed approach (probably worse performance than above!):

Main (original) template

```
<ul>
  {exp:search:search_results search_in="everywhere"}
    {if language_code =="it"}
      <li><a href="{exp:replace_plus find='.com/' replace='.com/it/'}{auto_path}{/exp:replace_plus}">{embed=crap/language-title entry_id="{entry_id}" channel_name="{channel_name}"}</a> (trovato in {channel}) {embed=crap/language-title entry_id="{entry_id}" channel_name="{channel_name}"}</li>
    {if:else}
      <li"><strong><h3><a href="{auto_path}">{embed=crap/language-title entry_id="{entry_id}" channel_name="{channel_name}"}</a></h3></strong> (from {channel}){embed=crap/language-title entry_id="{entry_id}" channel_name="{channel_name}"}</li>
    {/if}
  {/exp:search:search_results}
</ul>
```

New embed template called "language-title"

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" cache="yes" refresh="60"}
    {{embed:channel_name}_title_{language_code}}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This works (if you can call it that) because the embed variable is parsed before the tag pair variables and as detailed, the language_code is parsed before too - so leaves the correctly named variable tag ready for EE to parse correctly.

**1st Edit:**

`{{channel_name}_title_{language_code}}` not `{channel_name}_title_{language_code}`

```
{if language_code =="it"}
    <li><a href="{exp:replace_plus find='.com/' replace='.com/it/'}{auto_path}{/exp:replace_plus}">{{channel_name}_title_{language_code}}</a> (trovato in {channel}) {{channel_name}_body_{language_code}}</li>
{if:else}
    <li"><strong><h3><a href="{auto_path}">{{channel_name}_title_{language_code}}</a></h3></strong> (from {channel}){{channel_name}_body_{language_code}}</li>
{/if}
```

Note: channel_name is valid although not documented [ref](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-short-name)

But, the problem is this would assume that it parses for tag variables in the template twice: once to replace `{channel_name}`, then parse again the result `{{channel_name}_title_it}` - note that `{language_code}` would have been parsed much earlier being a config variable. Without trying to confirm it might be clever enough to parse the inner variable first, but failing that you could try [stashing as a variable first](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) or outputting the channel name from a [separate plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-value)?

Note to self: Must read question!

Ignore the below as got wrong variable not parsing!

---

<del>You can read more on Parse order [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html). But basically tags (modules, etc) get parsed before the custom global variables, so your {language_code} is getting parsed after it's needed :(</del>

<del>If the example code you've given is in an embedded template, then you could pass the variable from the previous template into the new one, e.g.</del>

<del>Root template:</del>

```
{embed=template-group/template-name language="{language_code}"}
```

<del>Then in the template use:</del>

```
{embed:language}
```

<del>This works because the parse order is relevant to each template - not globally, so the first template goes through most of the parsing before the embedded one.</del>

<del>Alternatively and probably the best solution (besides using a [specific module for multi-language](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=multi%20language&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2)) is to set the global variable in the config or index.php, without knowing more on your build of how the language_code is being set it's difficult to offer any further solutions.</del>

<del>Is language based on the user preference? Is it based on segment?  Are you using differing index.php for each language to rewrite the url, so it appears but is not considered a segment?</del>

Also don't forget [ExpressionEngine's dedicated StackOverflow site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Peter, thanks for your detailed reply. The language is based on segment and I am using differing index.php for each language. the variable {language_code} is set in each language folder in index.php as a global variable. However, in my case {channel_name}_title_{language_code} it's the {channel_name} which is not rendered, because if I write {blog_title_{language_code}} or {news_title_{language_code}} this works, but if I write {{channel_name}_title_en} or {{channel_name}_title_it} this does not work. I need to dynamically get the name of the channel in the search result and show entry title.

Comment: ooops. Although your comment might provide the answer: your example code states "{channel_name}_title_en" but your comment states "{{channel_name}_title_en} - the former wouldn't work, but the latter should because of the extra curlies. Have updated my answer.

Comment: Why have you got channel_name in the field name? The entry can only belong to one channel, so can never usable values in other "named" channel fields.  If you share a field group across multiple channels, they can all use the same field (e.g. body_it or body_en).

Comment: Thanks Peter. {{channel_name}_title_{language_code}} was my first attempt with no luck. This just displays "{news_title_it}". To answer your question, I use channel name in the field name because I have to display a search results which looks in more than one channel, so I need to display the entry correct title according to language (stored in the custom fields: {channel_name}_title_{language_code}. If I don't use custom field, the search results would always display the "title" which is stored only in english. {{channel_name}_title_en} also fails, while {news_title_{language_code}} works.

Comment: That's fine to use a custom field, by why bother with the {channel_name} in front of it? I'm assuming it's because you have separate field groups for each channel, therefore different fields and need to identify them based on the channel. I'll update my answer with the Stash solution, although not elegant, it should work.

Comment: Yes you're correct Peter. I read something about stash. I'll wait for your update, many thanks!